# C# code to add hyper link in excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I am having an excel file containing multiple sheets.
One of the sheets will contain the hyperlink for other sheets.

While using the  following code I have successfully added the link but 
when I click on the link it gives error  `**"Refrence not valid"**`

Code snippet:

```
private void AddHyperLink(Workbook xlWorkBook,int nfaultCount)
{        

   Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Summary"; //name of the sheet containing hyperlink

        xlWorkSheet.Select(Type.Missing); //code to select the summary sheet

        for (int i = 1; i <= nfaultCount; i++)
        {
            int x = i + 9;

            string str = "Fault Code "+i + " of " + nfaultCount;

            string strRange1 = "A" + x;

            string strRange2 = "A" + x;

            string strRange = strRange1 + ":" + strRange2; //location of the link

             var Range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(strRange);

           // strRange1 = "!" + strRange1;
            string strp="#" + i + " of " +nfaultCount + strRange1;

             i +" of " nfaultCount==> name of the target worksheet

           Range.Cells.Hyperlinks.Add(Range,strp, Type.Missing, "Fault Code Link", str);
        }

        xlWorkSheet.Columns["A:B"].AutoFit();
```

}

I  have used the following link for my refrence 
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_27912390.html

but its giving error Refrence is not valid.

Comment: On which line you are getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says your hyperlink address is invalid.

Try generating it as:

```
string strp="#'" + i + " of " +nfaultCount + "'!" + strRange1;
// Sample result: "#'4 of 5'!A3
```

instead of

```
string strp="#" + i + " of " +nfaultCount + strRange1;
// Sample result: #4 of 5A3
```

The above assumes the target worksheet name is "4 of 5".

Note that you need a ! character between the worksheet name and the range name.
You also need to enclose the worksheet name in single quotes if it contains one or more spaces.